Why I got bad request while startRoomCompositeEgress in liveKit
I'm trying to record video from camera and post it to google cloud. My frontend is in VueJS and I have Node.js server.
Basically on front I've got method to start recording:
const startVideo = async () => {
  await room.localParticipant.enableCameraAndMicrophone()

  const tracks = await createLocalTracks({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  })
  if (room && room.localParticipant) {
    tracks.forEach(track => {
      room.localParticipant.publishTrack(track)
    })
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/start-recording', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ roomName: room.name })
    })

    const data = await response.json()
    console.log('Recording started...', data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while starting recording:', error)
  }
}

I'm connected to the proper room, have proper token etc.
On Node.js server side I have method which run startRecording:
app.post('/start-recording', async (req, res) => {
  const { roomName } = req.body
  
  try {
    const egressId = await startRecording(roomName)
    res.send({ message: 'Recording started', egressId })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error while start recording', error })
  }
})

and method which should start room composite egress to capture video and sent it to google cloud:
async function startRecording(roomName) {
  try {
    const filepath = `recordings/${roomName}_${Date.now()}.mp4`

    const fileOutput = new EncodedFileOutput({
      filepath,
      output: {
        case: 'gcp',
        value: new GCPUpload({
          credentials,
          bucket: bucket.id
        })
      }
    })
  
    const response = await egressClient.startRoomCompositeEgress(
      roomName,
      {
        layout: 'grid',
        video_bitrate: 4500,
        width: 1280,
        height: 720
      }
    )
    
    return response.egress_id
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while starting recording:', error)
    throw error
  }
}


I'm passing proper room name, bucket name, all credentials are fine. But from some reason I have that error. I've tried debug and error occurs in TwirRpc.js while making some POST request.
https://docs.livekit.io/home/egress/room-composite/#roomcomposite-egress Here is documentation which I've used. But there is no information about GCP.. I got all required fields from library code.
Maybe I'm missing smth in configuration?

i implemented it in golang the path should be somthing like this
Filepath: fmt.Sprintf("/out/%v.mp4", fileName),

and in the docker compose file
  egress:
    image: livekit/egress:latest
    container_name: egress
    command: --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -e EGRESS_CONFIG_FILE=/out/livekit-egress.yaml -v /out
    environment:
      EGRESS_CONFIG_FILE: /out/livekit-egress.yaml
    volumes:
      - ./egress:/out
    networks:
      - livekit-network
    depends_on:
      - livekit-server

this line
volumes:
      - ./egress:/out

redirect the save file to your local folder in the above case is egress folder
the above example is for local saving not google cloud
